# Stack pointer changing on runtime

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

I have a question about stack pointer changing in atmega328p. Suppose I'm writing such procedure:

```
example:
    ; save stack pointer to X register
    in r26, SPL
    in r27, SPH
    push r16
    push r17
    push r18
    …
    out SPL, r26
    out SPH, r27
    ret
```

The problem is, that out instruction doesn't change SPL and SPH registers. Can I change those registers directly or they only can be changed by other instructions (push, pop, call...)? I had found, that on reset I can initialize them, but nothing more...

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? The compiler also generates such code, although you should be careful about interrupts.

Comment: After out SPL value in r26 and SPL register are different, so at least for me it doesn't work. Maybe there is some bit in one of control registers that should be set before changing stack pointer. But for now I haven't found any info about that. I will try to initialize stack pointer registers directly in the beginning of program. Maybe it will help. In all sources I see, such description "To use SRAM as stack requires the setting of the stack pointer first.", but I was skipping that step.